# If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, is $Z=(X, Y)$ a random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variable

What definition do we use for random variable? How do we show that $Z=(X,Y)$ is a random variable?

Comment: What do you mean by the brackets?

Comment: It is a bivariate distribution for a random vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We would call $Z$ a **random vector** (but yes, it is random).

Random variables are defined within a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) that includes a [sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space) $\Omega$.  Within such a space, real-valued random variables $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are functions$^\dagger$ from the sample space to Euclidean space.  You have $Z \equiv (X,Y)$ so $Z(\omega) = (X(\omega), Y(\omega)) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$, which means that the latter is a mapping $Z:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.$^\dagger$  This means that it is a two-element real random vector.

---

$^\dagger$ Formally, random variables must be [measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function) functions, which is a formal requirement from measure theory.  If you are new to dealing with random variables, just ignore this part; I mention it for completeness.  It can be shown that measureability of $X$ and $Y$ implies measureability of $Z$, so this requirement is met in this case.  (Hat-tip to [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) in the comments for noting the importance of the latter property.)

Comment: Since you're being formal--which is fine--consider including a remark about the key idea, which is that the measurability of $X$ and $Y$ implies the measurability of $Z$ with respect to the product measure on $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: If we have a theorem which is true for a random variable, e.g., it is true for $X$ and $Y$, is it true for a random vector $Z=(X,Y)$? Can we apply the theorem to this random vector?

Comment: There's no such general theorem simply because $Z$ has different mathematical properties than $X$.  For instance, values of $Z$ cannot be ordered whereas values of $X$ can be, so any theorem that refers to ordering values of $X$ couldn't be applied to $Z.$  The solution to your problem is obtained simply by applying the definitions of measurability and product measure.

Comment: @whuber Regarding measurability only, we do not need introduce any measure. Specifically, not product measure. To my knowledge, product measure refers to the case that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, while here OP clearly doesn't restrict to be that case.

Comment: @Zhanxiong You lost me, because measure is defined without reference to any random variable.  Measurability of a random variable is with respect to the Borel sigma field on $\mathbb{R}$ and measurability of a 2D random variable is with respect to the Borel sigma field on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. I don't see how you can even talk about a 2D "random variable" without having a measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the first place.

Comment: @whuber To talk about measurability, what you only need is a measurable space, which doesn't need to be equipped with any measure. Please refer to Section 13 of Billingsley's book. I certainly can talk about a 2D random variable without having a measure on $\Omega$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$ in mathematical sense (though it is less interesting in application). After all, random variables/vectors are nothing but functions/mappings.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I agree with all that: the issue is one of pulling back the Borel sigma algebra, pure and simple.  My understanding of the term "measurable" in this context does not include that a measure *is* defined, but that the collections of measurable sets (that is, the sigma algebras) on $\Omega$ and $\mathbb R$ are determined.

Comment: @whuber Zhanxiong: My understanding of this is the same as [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) - i.e., you need to be able to form a sigma-field on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  I have edited my answer to move all the measurability stuff to a footnote, so that the OP is not scared off with a bunch of formal measure theory.

Comment: @Ben Just make it clear, to form a sigma-field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ doesn't need to specify a measure --- that's all my point, I didn't say we don't need a sigma-field.

Comment: @Zhanxiong: Sorry, I am probably not explaining myself well.  My understanding is that we want to ensure that $Z = (X,Y)$ is a measureable function, which means that we want to ensure that the class $\{ Z(\mathcal{E}) | \mathcal{E} \in \mathscr{F} \}$ is a sigma-field (where $\mathscr{F}$ is the sigma field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the original probability space).  So long as you can ensure that this class is a sigma-field (which it is), you can say that $Z$ is a measureable function to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then you're fine.

Answer (score 2):

To be formal, you need to set up a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ (to discuss the measurability only, the probability measure $P$ is even not required, as the argument below shows). What you want to confirm is that given $X$ and $Y$ are two $\mathscr{F}$-measurable mappings from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$, then $Z$ is an $\mathscr{F}$-measurable mapping from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

This is ready to check by noting that for any $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we have 
\begin{align}
& \{\omega: Z(\omega) \leq (x, y)\} \\
= & \{\omega: X(\omega) \leq x, Y(\omega) \leq y\} \\
= & \{\omega: X(\omega) \leq x\} \cap \{\omega: Y(\omega) \leq y\} \in \mathscr{F}
\end{align}
as both sets after the last equality sign are in $\mathscr{F}$ by measurability of $X$ and $Y$ and that the $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{F}$ is closed under intersection.

Note also the converse of the statement is also true: if $Z$ is a random vector, then each of its component is a random variable.